# default constraint not firing

Tags: sql-server

added Default Constraint on a Foreign key column for default value so if the user does not supply value default value should be inserted. but instead of firing constraint, it shows **Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

--Table--

```
create table tblperson(
    Id int not null, 
    Name nvarchar(50) not null, 
    Email nvarhcar(50) not null, 
    GenderId int
);
```

--tblGender--

```
Create Table tblGender(
    ID int Not Null Primary Key,
    Gender nvarchar(50)
);
```

--Add foreign Key--

```
Alter table tblPerson 
add constraint tblPerson_GenderId_FK FOREIGN KEY (GenderId) references tblGender(ID)
```

--Default Constraint--

```
ALTER TABLE tblPerson
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_tblPerson_GenderId
DEFAULT 1 FOR GenderId
```

--Insert Statement--

```
insert into tblperson values(5,'Jake','j@j.com')
```

Comment: Add the `INSERT` statement that raises the error. Most likely,the column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: insert into tblperson values(5,'Jake','j@j.com')

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is:

```
insert into tblperson(Id, Name, Email) values(1,'Jake','j@j.com');
```

Most of people forget to write the columns names, you should always be carful of the columns names and the number of supplied values.

BTW, fix the typo in this line:

```
Email nvarhcar(50) not null,
```

it should be:

```
Email nvarchar(50) not null,
```

Comment: @MANISHKISHORE Glad to help, please read **[this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358870/6426692)**.